# Filter issue when using RequestParamater from express.js on filtering JSON object

Tags: node.js, express, filter

I have an issue when filtering JSON object. When I set value of filterParameter statically there is no problem. But there is an issue when getting from req.query.categoryId

```
const paramCategory = req.query.categoryId;
```

This is what I wrote:

```
result = result.filter((x) => x.categoryId === paramCategory);
```

This is what it worked:

```
result = result.filter((x) => x.categoryId === 1);
```

I read paramCategory from console.log() but when I filtering I ve an issue.

Comment: You are using strict equality `===` so probably in result array categoryId is a number, and req.query.categoryIId is a string. So 1 === "1" is false. But 1 == "1" is true.

Comment: yeah that works. but I could not understant  when I wrote req.query.categoryId it returns 1(number) (not string). thank you. @SergeySosunov